# Context menu items and subitems

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a ContextMenuStrip inside a form.

For some reason, I want to change all items of the context menu simultaneously. So I wrote this peace of code:

```
int a = 0; 

foreach (ToolStripItem co in contextMenuStrip1.Items)  
{     
 co.Text = "Menu" + a.ToString();
  a++;
  }
```

But although the main items change succesfully, the subitems doesn't change
So how can I have access to those subitems too?

PS: I cannot add an image because I am new to this forum to see what I mean, I hope you get the idea.

Thanks!

Comment: You will need a recursive function.

Comment: I don't understand ... do you have a ContextMenu, which you open with right mouse button, or do you have a ToolBar, which usually sits in the upper part of your window? Because you use 2 different terms.

Comment: Host the image some where and get the link for it here.

Comment: @dowhilefor - a quick search for `ContextMenuStrip` finds it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx) and one of its ancestor types is `ToolStrip`. I don't see Tool**Bar** used anywhere in this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast to `ToolStripDropDownItem` and check the `DropDownItems` property. And, of cource, update it recursively.

here is the sample:

```
public void ChangeMenuItemsNames(ToolStripItemCollection collection)
    {
        foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in collection)
        {
            item.Name = "New Name";

            if (item is ToolStripDropDownItem)
            {
                ToolStripDropDownItem dropDownItem = (ToolStripDropDownItem)item;

                if (dropDownItem.DropDownItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    this.ChangeMenuItemsNames(dropDownItem.DropDownItems);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How to use:

```
   this.ChangeMenuItemsNames(this.contextMenuStrip1.Items);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems it is working, let me work on it for a while and I will then post again for feedback.

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you very much, I have some problems with ToolStrip, but I am working on it. I will post back when I'm stuck again.

Answer (score 0):

Since as per MSDN, ToolStripButton,ToolStripLabel,ToolStripSeparator,ToolStripControlHost,ToolStripDropDownItem,ToolStripStatusLabel do inherit from ToolStripItem, you can try casting with as operator and then setting its text property as well.

Hope this is what your asking for.

Comment: I will tell you in detail: I want to change the language (culture) during runtime. All controls changes their name, except ContextMenuStrip, MenuStrip and ToolStrip. I found a way to change the names of these three as well, but only the main items, not the subitems.

Comment: All items whitch have sub-items are ToolStripDropDownItem. Checkout my answer.

Comment: Yep samich is talking more of what i did!

Comment: foreach (ToolStripItem co in contextMenuStrip1.Items) //menu.Items)
{
  string text = resourcesss.GetString(co.Name + ".Text", cult);
  if (text != null)
  {
    co.Text = text;
  }
}
            
How can I rewrite this code to have acces to ToolStripDropDownItem too?

Comment: (co as ToolStripDropDownItem).DropDownItems will fetch you subitems. Then debug it to see what items its fetching. As Samich says, recursively iterate.

Answer (score 0):

```
  void ChangeName(ToolStripItemCollection collection, ref int a)
    {
        foreach (ToolStripItem co in collection)
        {
            co.Text = "Menu" + a.ToString();
            a++;
            if (co is ToolStripDropDownItem)
            {
                ToolStripDropDownItem ts = co as ToolStripDropDownItem;
                if (ts.DropDownItems != null) ChangeName(ts.DropDownItems, ref a);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no co.Items =) I thought about it firsthand, but it's just a wrong assumption.